# Wrap div not rendering in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

I have a `render()` function that returns a div with content inside of it, such as:

```
return(
    <div style={{background: "black"}}>
        <[ReactComponent]>
            <[AnotherReactComponent]>
                ...
            </[AnotherReactComponent]>
        </[ReactComponent]>
    </div>
);
```

When I inspect the element, the outer div does not render, however the `ReactComponent` does.

Comment: Can you add flex:1 for outer div ?

Comment: @Ajith I added and it does not show up as well.

Comment: Is the div rendered on the DOM? Or are you saying you just can't see it.
Because if it's in the DOM you have css issues.
Can you take a screen shot of what you see under "inspect element" in dev tools?

Comment: @DanielDuong Sorry for the mistake, it simply does not render, however all the React Components do. (Sorry, cannot take a screenshot)

Comment: Do you see the `<div>` in the DOM ? Try to add a width and height in pixels

Comment: @Weedoze No, I can't see the div, because it does not render.

Comment: @DuarteCastanho Just because you can't see it. Doesn't mean it hasn't rendered.
https://zapier.com/blog/inspect-element-tutorial/
Please check the dom and tell us if it's there.

Comment: @DanielDuong It is not rendering, i can see in the inspector, therefore does not show up.

Comment: @DuarteCastanho There is a difference between seeing the div in your browser and seeing it inside the DOM (via your developer console). 2nd thought : Can you put `console.log("test")` inside the `render()` function ?

Comment: Guys I have already inspected the DOM through the console, the div does not exist.

Comment: @DuarteCastanho Okay. Well the problem is not with your JSX. I would try restarting your app, making sure you saved or open in incognito.

Comment: Are you using react native?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should add some construction like this in the render method of RComponent

```
<View>{props.children}</View>
```